# Extend divs height to fill up unused space

Tags: html, css

On http://ahti.stabe.de/blogRedesign/ I have a container (#wrapper) which contains `#top`,  `#navi` and `#cont`.

In the case that not enough content is given in `#cont` (which is the case right now on 1680x1050) I want the white Background area to extend to the bottom of the page anyhow.

I tried setting `height: 100%;` on various elements, but this always caused a scrollbar to appear/the page to be scrollable by 1px or so.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `height: 100%` to the `#cont` tag then you are making it 100% that ELEMENT to 100% the height of the window + whatever is on top/below it it doesn't fill 100% of the window like you think,

AListApart have a great article on vertical stretch using faux columns:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/